# How can I get/pass the identifier to shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have a an app that has a sidebar menu. My side bar menu has 6 items on it. Items 0-4 will perform segue and move to destination view controller. But item 5 (feedback) when it is tapped should pop up an alert view and not move to another view controller. The solution I thought of is to use shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier.
Here's what i've got so far:

```
- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender
{
    BOOL isToDetail = true;
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"FEEDBACK"])
    {
        isToDetail = false;
    }
    else
    {
        isToDetail = true;
    }

    return isToDetail;
}
```

Now my concern here is, that everytime it goes thru this code the **identifier** is always null so it always goes to else instead of the if block. How can I get the identifier?

Comment: how you created segue.

Comment: Just check you getting correct segue identifier. use break point.

Comment: @BrittoThomas in my storyboard i added a segue, then i set the identifier to "FEEDBACK", segue is set to CUSTOM and segue class is SWREVEALVIEWCONTROLLERSEGUE..thats how i set up my segue...

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the segue identifier in the Storyboard
Just open your Storyboard, select the segue, and on the Right panel add a unique identifier as showed here

[image: Storyboard Segue Identifier]

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a segue to display an alert view because it is not a ViewController.

What you can do is create an IBAction in your code then link the tap event from the "item 5" to the IBAction.

What will happen is that when the button is tapped (usually the event is Touch Up Inside), it will call your IBAction and execute your code. You can find information on the new Alert Views of iOS below:

http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/